# If $U$ is a subspace of a vector space $V$, then it is also a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If we define $U$ as a subspace of a vector space $V$ then does that mean that $U$ is also a vector space?

Comment: What's the definition of a subspace that you're using? Most would take it to be part of the definition. Much like how a subset is automatically a set.

Comment: The principal reason we're interested in subspaces is because they're vector spaces themselves.

Comment: I was just wondering because to prove that a spanning set is a subspace you only need to prove that it's closed under addition, under scalar multiplication and isn't empty. Where as to prove that  something is a vector space you need to prove 10 different properties including the ones for vector spaces. So in theory, proving that it's a subspace doesn't automatically prove that it's a vector space. However, when a subspace is a subset of a vector space then it's also a vector space?

Comment: The usual definition of a subspace $U$ of a vector space $V$ is that it is a subset of $V$ which, under the vector addition, and scalar multiplication of $V$, is itself a vector space. With this definition, it is trivially true that a subspace $U$ is a vector space.

Comment: @DanielRust that clears things up. So as long as a subspace is a subset of a vector space, it is also a vector space.

However, if we are not told that the subspace is a subset of a vector space then we can't assume that it's also a vector space?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by 'we are not told that the subspace is a subset of a vector space'. It doesn't make sense to talk about something 'being a subspace' of something else, unless that something else is a vector space. For instance, what is a subspace of the set $\{0,1\}$? Given that $\{0,1\}$ isn't a priori a vector space, it can't have any subspaces (only subsets).

Answer (score 3):

Let $V$ be a vector space and let $W$ be a subset of $V$.  We have two equivalent definitions of a "subspace":

*Definition 1*:  If $W$ is a vector space, then $W$ is a *subspace* of $V$.

*Definition 2*:  If $W$ satisfies the following

- $W$ is non-empty;
- $W$ is closed under vector addition;
- $W$ is closed under scalar multiplication,

then $W$ is a *subspace* of $V$.

[A third definition replaces "$W$ is non-empty" with "$W$ contains the zero vector" in Definition 2.]

We can check these are equivalent:  If $W$ is a vector space, then it satisfies the conditions of Definition 2, by definition of a vector space.  Conversely, if $W$ satisfies the conditions of Definition 2, we can check that all of the [vector space axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition) are hold.

Comment: It should be made clear in Definition 1 that $W$ is a vector space using the same operations as those on $V$.

Comment: So all subspaces are vector spaces?

Comment: Yes, in fact "subspace" is just a succinct way of writing "sub-vector-space".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is trivially true if you use the usual definition of a subspace of a vector space $V$, which is a subset $U$ which is also a vector space under the vector addition and scalar multiplication of $V$.

If you are using some other definition (for instance 'a subspace $U$ of a vector space $V$ is a span of some subset of $V$'), then you may have some work to do to show that such a thing is a vector space. For instance in the above definition in terms of spans, one would need to show that a span of elements in a vector space is a vector space.

Suppose our definition of a subspace is the following:

> Let $V$ be a vector space. $U$ is a subspace of $V$ if there exists a linear transformation $T\colon V\to V$ such that $U=\ker T=\{u\in V\mid T(u)=0\}$.

This is one possible definition of a subspace (for finite dimensional vector spaces anyway) which you might not have seen, but it can be shown to be equivalent to the usual definition. From this definition we can show that a subspace is a vector space with the inherited vector addition and scalar multiplication.

Indeed, $T(0)=0$ because $T$ is linear and so $0\in U$. Also, for all $u,v\in U$ we have $T(u)=T(v)=0$ so and so $T(u+v)=0$ because $T$ is linear. It follows that $u+v\in\ker T$ and so $u+v\in U$.

Similarly, for any $\alpha\in K$ the base field, we have $T(\alpha u)=\alpha T(u)$ because $T$ is linear and so $T(\alpha u)=\alpha.0=0$ so $\alpha u\in\ker T\implies \alpha u\in U$.

Hence, $U$ satisfies all the properties of being a subspace of $V$ under the usual definition.

Now, to further show that $U$ is a vector space, we simply mention that $+|_U$ is associative, commutative and distributive over scalar multiplication because $+$ is associative, commutative and distributive over scalar multiplication in $V$. We also have that $1\in F$ is an identity of scalar multiplication restricted to $U$ because it is an identity of scalar multiplication on $V$, and scalar multiplication is compatible with field multiplication because it is in $V$. Similarly, because $0$ is in $U$, $U$ has an identity under addition given by the same zero. This proves that $U$ is a vector space itself.